# How accurately can Federation ships detect a vessel fleeing at warp speed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-picard

Suppose I'm on a Starfleet ship, between TNG-era and Picard era. I'm near another vessel that enters warp and I wish to pursue it.

What are the limits of my ship's ability to detect the position and direction of that vessel?

Comment: Watching Picard my jaw dropped when they warped in, stopped, and then turned on the cloak right next to a hostile ship.  LOL. Starships leave subspace wakes that can be measured light-years away.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Cloaked vessels also distort their subspace wake to prevent detection. This seems to be a general function and not one that's reliant on the cloak being on.

Comment: I've edited out a lot of the chatter here. I think this boils down to *"how accurate are the sensors at short, medium and long range"*

Comment: @Valorum: Ok, but - my question is about capital ships, not smaller ones.

Comment: @einpoklum - By "capital" do you specifically mean Galaxy-Class? Ship size doesn't particularly seem to equate to sensor capability

Comment: @Valorum: No, I mean the "larger" ships. See [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Capital_ship). Smaller ships may have weaker sensors.

Comment: @einpoklum - We have no indication that this designation is used prior to the Lower Decks episode, so if you're after TNG era ships, you're going to need to be more specific. Also, different races will have differently powerful sensors.

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in the *[Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual)*

> 10.2 LONG-RANGE SENSORS
>
> The most powerful scientific instruments aboard the USS
> Enterprise are probably those located in the long-range
> sensor array. This cluster of high-power active and passive
> subspace frequency sensors is located in the Engineering
> Hull directly behind the main deflector dish.
>
> The majority of instruments in the long-range array are
> active scan subspace devices, which permit information gathering at speeds greatly exceeding that of light. Maximum
> effective range of this array is approximately five light years in
> high-resolution mode. **Operation in medium-to-low resolution
> mode yields a usable range of approximately 17 light years
> (depending on instrument type).** At this range, a sensor scan
> pulse transmitted at Warp 9.9997 would take approximately
> forty-five minutes to reach its destination and another forty five minutes to return to the Enterprise. Standard scan protocols permit comprehensive study of approximately one adjacent sector per day at this rate. Within the confines of a solar system, the long-range sensor array is capable of providing nearly instantaneous information.
>
> Primary instruments in the long-range array include:
> • Wide-angle active EM scanner
> • Narrow-angle active EM scanner